# Why is data passed to component is causing TypeError: undefined error? Shows up in React dev tools

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jsx

I am passing state data to props through mapStateToProps, but it is not recognized in the component.

```js
// user_show_container
// propper import statements....
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  ids: state.entities.users.usersById.leagueIds;
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  requestTargetUserData: id => dispatch(requestTargetUserData(id)),
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(UserShow);
```

Action is called in 'componentWillMount()' and the props should be available

```js
class UserShow extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.requestTargetUserData(this.props.match.params.userId)
  }

  render() {
    const { ids } = this.props; // [1, 2, 3]

    return (
      <div className="">
        <ul>
          {ids.map(id => <li>id</li>)} // causes error
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserShow;
```

[image]

When I remove the map function and do not render with data from props, the Redux dev tools show that the 'id' array is available to the component.
[image]

This is not happening with everything that is passed through props. For example swapping this out works. The username is rendered to the page.

```js
  ...
   return (
      <div className="">
        <h1>{targetUser.username}</h1>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default UserShow;
```

[image]

I'm really at a loss here so any guidance would be hugely appreciated. It feels like I am missing something basic, but I haven't been able to find any answers.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: what is initial value of `state.entities.users.usersById.leagueIds` in reducer? api calls will be async and component will get rendered before api success, make sure the default value of `ids` should be `[]`.

Answer (score 1):

**Issue is with initialisation :**

You should initiate the :

`state.entities.users.usersById.leagueIds` with `[]` ,
for the first time and also if the value is not available.

---

In you case `state.entities.users.usersById.leagueIds` will be undefined, that's the only reason you are getting error of

> Cannot read property of 'map' of undefined

---

If you don't want to initialise, you can do this also :

```
const ids = this.props.ids ? this.props.ids : [];
```

Or Shorter form as @MayankShukla suggested in comment:

```
const ids = this.props.ids || [];
```

Comment: or simply `const ids = this.props.ids || []` :)

Comment: @MayankShukla , yeah :D

Comment: Ah, I see. So the ‘const { ids } = this.props;’ is undefined, even though the action that will provide that data is dispatched in ‘componentWillMount’? Where in the component should I initiate? The value of ‘const { ids } will be updated from [ ] to the correct data once the async action is complete. Is that correct?

Comment: @DavidSawatske , yes :)

Comment: @DavidSawatske ,you should initiate it from reducer, render will be called each time prop or state changes,

Comment: @DavidSawatske, will you please upvote and accept the answer if this provide you the solution you wanted ?

Comment: @VivekDoshi No problem. One quick question: the **<h1>targetUser.username<h1>** is also passed in a props and would have an initial value of undefined until the asynchronous action is resolved. Could you please help me understand why that is rendered without error? Thanks again for all of your help.

Comment: beacuse you are doing any operation upon it , and it will consider it as undefined and dont print anything , try to execute targetUser.username.length you will get the error like before,

Comment: @DavidSawatske, will you please also accept the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this `state.entities.users.usersById.leagueIds` returning an array? Because if it returned undefined, that could also be the reason for the error.

```
const mappStateToProps = state => ({
   ids: ["1", "2", "3"]
});
```

Try setting the above to see if you still see the error. If the error subsides, then it means your `ids` information is populated after the component is rendered?